# How to get the value (not the code) of codemirror textarea

Tags: html, angularjs, codemirror

How to get the value of codemirror textearea, my code is fallow

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h4 class="portlet-title">
        <u>Descriptif du fichier</u>
    </h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="sample"
            ui-codemirror="{
    theme:'twilight',
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: 'xml'
}">
$demand.sample
</div>
```

js

```
var myTextArea = document.getElementById("sample");
    var editor = CodeMirror(function(elt) {
          myTextArea.parentNode.replaceChild(elt, myTextArea);
        }, {value: myTextArea.innerHTML});

    alert ("type "+editor.getValue());
```

with this, it get me all code, but i want just get the value not the code

Comment: I'm not clear about what you want. What do you mean by "all code" and by "value not the code"

By definition *getValue* delivers "the current editor content". See here: https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api